# Display data in div on click by data attribute which has secondary div with same data attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 3 `div`s, each with a different `data` attribute:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="item" data-category="#music"> CLICK </div> 
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="item" data-category="#movies"> CLICK </div> 
</div>

.
.
.
```

I made script which activates a hidden dialog box:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('#dialogbox').show();
});
```

I have divs, with `id`s that are the same as a `data-category` attribute:

```
<div id="music"> ALL INFORMATION ABOUT MUSIC </div>
<div id="movies"> ALL INFORMATION ABOUT MOVIES </div>
.
.
.
```

**My question:**

How can I display information from all of the ***ALL INFORMATION*** `div`s in `dialogbox` by the clicked `data-category`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).find('.item').data('category'); //replace with $(this).find('.item').attr('data-category') if fails

    var message = $(id).html();
    //now write your code here to push this message inside certain div of dialogbox, i assume message is the id
    $("#message").html(message);

    //then finally show
    $('#dialogbox').show();
});
```

Comment: I dont get it. What is purpose of #message? if i am clicking on data-category="#movies", than div with id="movies" should be displayed in dialogbox.